# Eclipse wont open Android Xml files

Tags: xml, android, eclipse

I'm just starting with Android and everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to look at any XML file in eclipse, I get the following error.  The only way I can see them is by "Opening With" -> TextFile.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error opening the Android XML editor. Is the document an XML file?
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.createTextEditor(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.createAndroidPages(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.addPages(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
 at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:357)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:662)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:462)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:286)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2857)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2762)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2754)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2705)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2701)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2685)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2676)
 at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
 at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:361)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
 at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:842)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:840)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1101)
 at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1205)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
 at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before. Sometimes (no guarantees!) installing the latest JRE/JDK helps.

Answer (score 0):

This morning I updated the ADT plugins, and got the same problems.

The solution was to uninstall the latest version of the plugins, and then download previous versions (you could try this one http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-8.0.1.zip while http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-9.0.0.zip if to follow a standard file naming convention is not available) and then install the plugins as a local archive. Then the problem is fixed.

I suppose that this is a major bug in the latest version of the ADT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ive got this issue too now. Its really annoying. The thing is, if you uninstall the plugins, and install the older versions, you will come across the issue with the SDK being too up to date for the plugins, asking you to then update again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update all software by going to: Help > Check for updates and update all the softwares and that should sort it.